# Sqlite3 Amalgamation on iPhone misbehaving GANTRacker

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I added Sqlite3 3.7.3 amalgamation to my iPhone project which has already been using CoreData and the embedded Sqlite3 libraries for iOS.

However, I needed to add FTS3 support for another sqlite db file in the project that I will be accessing directly (without CoreData's Help)

In order to do this I had to add the sqlite3 amalgamation which seems to work fine in the simulator but when I run it on a device at startup I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The breakpoint seems to stop in sqlite3.c in the setPageSize function which is being caused by GANTracker

Is there a known configuration change I need to make to the amalgamation to get it to support GANTracker?

Comment: Further debugging has shown that it is in function..sqlite3PagerSetPagesize(Pager *pPager, u32 *pPageSize, int nReserve) ... The pPageSize pointer is NULL and therefore the line u32 pageSize  = *pPageSize; is throwing the error. Why is this variable null?

Comment: Seems to be the GANTracker and not CoreData that is causing the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved my own issue. The cause was the Google Analytics api plugin. Make sure you are compiling with GCC 4.2 on the sqlite3 library and not LLVM